# Set isEmailVerified of already verified firebase Users to false

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

Every year i want my Firebase users to verify their account-email again, to check that their Email address are still in use.

To test this i sent a new verification email to my (already verified) account. The mail was sent, but this **did not** set my `.isEmailVerified` to false, also after reloading the `currentUser` and the app.

Does anyone know if it´s possible to set the `.isEmailVerified` to false, once it is true at all, and if so how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Sending a verification email does not set the `emailVerified` property to `false`. That is the expected and  intended behavior.

If you want to set the `emailVerified` property of a user to `false`, you can do so with the Firebase Admin SDK. For example, in Node.js it would be:

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
  emailVerified: false
})
```

For more examples (including in other languages) see the [Firebase documentation on updating a user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).

Note that the Admin SDK has full administrative access to your Firebase project, so should only be run from a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions for Firebase. In no instance should you try to put this functionality in the app you give to your uses, as doing so will give them administrative access to your Firebase project.

Comment: thank you for your answer! So the most simple way is to use an one-time loop for all users and set `emailVerified` to false?

Comment: If that is what you want to accomplish, then: yes.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the question asked by him and My question was different. But the answer same. Anyways. very much thanks! for helping me.