# set emailVerified to false programmatically in android

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

My question is based on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573021/set-isemailverified-of-already-verified-firebase-users-to-false), is it possible to do the same in android?

The `UserProfileChangeRequest` builder seems not having the instruction to update emailVerified; is it or I miss it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried implementing java code from this link - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user

Comment: no, that one is not the suitable code for my case, i'm talking about this - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile it seems the builder has no the setEmailVerified(true) option